# SQL SERVER 2016: Refactoring function to execute with default parameter

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have the `default_report` function to fetch last 24 months report

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.default_report
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT ID,sender,recipient,amount,currency
    FROM reports
    where submit_date >= dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,getdate())-24,0)
)
```

I have the `custom_report` function to fetch the report for specific dates

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.custom_report(@start_date DATE,@end_date DATE)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT ID,sender,recipient,amount,currency
    FROM reports
    where submit_date BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date
)
```

The only variable in the above two functions is the where clause, is there a way to combine the above two functions into one and make them work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.custom_report (
    @start_date DATE = NULL,
    @end_date DATE = NULL
) RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT ID, sender, recipient, amount, currency
        FROM reports
        WHERE submit_date >= COALESCE(@start_date, dateadd(month, -24, datefromparts(year(getdate()), month(getdate()), 1))) AND
              submit_date <= COALESCE(@end_date, getdate())
       );
```

I am guessing you have no future dates, so the condition on `@end_date` gets everything after the `@start_date` condition.

I also changed the calculation of the date 24 months ago so it is more intelligible.

Comment: Yes I dont have any future dates, I had to change the `@start_date DATE DEFAULT NULL` to `@start_date DATE` its working otherwise am getting `incorrect syntax near DEFAULT` compiler error

Comment: Also, quey works fine with NULL values `SELECT top 10 * FROM dbo.custom_reports(NULL,NULL)`

but if I run with input `SELECT top 10 * FROM dbo.custom_reports(1/1/2018,1/31/2018)` am getting `Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date`

Comment: @RanPaul. . . I always think the syntax for "default" parameters should use `default` rather than `=`.  I fixed the answer.  As for your second comment, dates should be surrounded by single quotes and in YYYY-MM-DD (or YYYYMMDD) format.